# Insert в таблицу

Tags: sql, insert

пытаюсь следующим запросом выполнить `insert` в таблицу1, при этом выбрав из таблицы2 id пользователя по фамилии.
Имеется такой запрос:

```
INSERT INTO Operations (CategoryID, ClientID, Description, DateOfOperation, ReturnDate, Amount, Commission) 
VALUES(1, 1, 'Тест', 10-06-2019, 10-06-2019, 15000, 17500), 
WHERE CategoryID =  'Иванов' 
FROM ProductCategory, ClientID = '' 
FROM Clients"
```

Но он, конечно же, не работает

Comment: Зачем вы поставили вопросу метку [tag:join] ?

Comment: поскольку ваш запрос не только сервер понять не в силах, но и простые люди, то лучше напишите, что конкретно вы хотите сделать с этими тремя таблицами, приведите пример данных, и на их основе сформируйте мысль, что вы хотите выбрать и куда вставить.

Comment: подозреваю, что имеется в виду нечто в виде `insert into opeations select client_id, ... from clients where clientName = 'вася пупкин'`

Comment: Необходимо в таблицу1 вставить запись, где значения первых двух полей (CatID и ClientID) берутся из таблицы2 по названию или фамилии (т.е. фамилия "Иванов" - ИД1, категория "Телевизор" - ИД1). Остальные значения берутся из textbox'ов

Answer (score 0, accepted):

insert into Operations (CategoryID, ClientID, Description, DateOfOperation, ReturnDate, Amount, Commission) 
values ((select ID from ProductCategory where Title = 'Телефон'), (select ID from Clients where Sname = 'Иванов'), 'Тест', '10-06-2019', '10-06-2019', 15000, 17500)

Так работает